# Case when statement with summed values in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a dataset with two columns. I want to categorise one of the columns into bins, and then sum the values in the other column that are within each bin.

I have tried the following code

```
select DISTINCT (
     CASE WHEN H=1 THEN '1'
     WHEN H BETWEEN 2 AND 3 THEN '2-3' 
     WHEN H BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN '4-6'
     ELSE '' END
) AS H , sum(V) [V]
from
  TABLE1 inner join TABLE 2 on TABLE1.X=TABLE2.X
where 
  TABLE.X=1 and Y='id' 
GROUP BY H
ORDER BY H ASC
```

The table below gives a sample of my data (where H and V are headers)

```
H      V
1      100
1      1000
1      1500
2      300
3      500
4      9000
5       800
6      1100
```

My desired output is

```
H          V
1          2600
2 TO 3     800
4 TO 6     10900
```

However, I am getting (ie. duplicated bins as column V is not being summed across all values in each bin)

```
H   V
1   100
1   1000
1   1500
2-3 300
2-3 500
4-6 9000
4-6 800
4-6 1100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation on a computed column:

```
select (CASE WHEN H = 1 THEN '1'
             WHEN H BETWEEN 2 AND 3 THEN '2-3'
             WHEN H BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN '4-6'
             ELSE ''
        END) AS H , sum(V) as V
from TABLE1 inner join
     TABLE2
     on TABLE1.X = TABLE2.X
where TABLE.X = 1 and Y = 'id'
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN H = 1 THEN '1'
               WHEN H BETWEEN 2 AND 3 THEN '2-3'
               WHEN H BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN '4-6'
               ELSE ''
          END)
ORDER BY MIN(H) ASC;
```

You should qualify all column references in the query.

`SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never appropriate with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: it seems like a sub query is simpler -- is there a reason to have the case statement twice ?

Comment: @Hogan . . . It depends on the database.  Some databases support column aliases in `GROUP BY`.  In others, I prefer a lateral join over a subquery.

Comment: I'm sad I didn't get to see the lateral join this time.